# Pre-compile a MVC 5 app mixed with Webform

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got a MVC 3 application mixed with web form with lots of "ascx" partial views included. The app is pre-compiled with no "updatable" content. So, there is not place holder markup for cshtml and ascx partial views the the Views folder. Everything was working fine until we recently updated the app to MVC 5. After updating, looks like the app doesn't find the "ascx" views anymore unless you create a dummy placeholder markup for every single user control. Otherwise you will get the following exception:

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The partial view '~/Views/Home/_PartialAscx.ascx' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/_PartialAscx.ascx
```

Please note that CSHTML partial views still work like a charm. My only problem is the ASCX views.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
```

Any advise on this issue would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It came out that it was a bug in MVC 5.1

https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1709